# Navbar logo to the right

Tags: html, css, navbar

I can't seem to put my logo to the right side of the navbar. I tried putting an additional class to it and looked for more solutions but none of them worked for me.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark">
            <img class="navbar-brand" src="***" style="width: 50px;height: auto;">
            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle colr" href="#"
                        id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown"> *** </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item colr" href="#"> ***</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> *** </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><s> *** </s></a>
                        </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link colr" href="#"> *** </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link colr" href="#"> *** </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link colr" href="#"> *** </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Are you using some css files to style this or you are just using some bootstrap classes ?

Comment: I'm only using the important ones, nothing else `.navbar {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 background-color: black !important;
 z-index: 1;
}`

Answer (score 0):

give the image some height and use float:right

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark">
            <img class="navbar-brand" src="***" style="width: 50px;float:right;height:50px;">
            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle colr" href="#"
                        id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown"> *** </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item colr" href="#"> ***</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> *** </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><s> *** </s></a>
                        </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link colr" href="#"> *** </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link colr" href="#"> *** </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link colr" href="#"> *** </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: I already tried to do that but it didn't work, sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: what's not working? is it working in the snippet the way you want??

Answer (score 0):

Try to add float:right in element:

```
'<img class="navbar-brand" src="***" style="width: 50px; float: right; height: auto">'
```

Comment: I already tried to float it to the right but it didn't work, thanks for your suggestion anyway!

Comment: hmm. but what's not working? As @DCR wrote in his snippet everything should be OK.